# Is the Roland SH 101 everywhere lately?

Tags: synthesizer

I love this synth. I have one sitting in the cupboard (sad I know!) Still, of late I've been hearing it (or a very close digital representation of it) everywhere in trance music of late. I've also noticed the prices have shot up beyond the measly two-figured price I paid for mine many years ago.

What genres is the SH 101 used in of late, and how is it used? As a bass or lead?

(please can someone with the permissions add the tags: roland and sh-101)

Comment: A Google search will throw-up lots of info on the SH-101.  You'll find a fairly full summary on Vintage Synth Explorer: http://www.vintagesynth.com/roland/sh101.php

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call this a full sumamry - a paradox in itself! The article is dated in itself. I think I've heard the music in trap and some forms of trance, and was just wondering why from users themselves

Answer (score 1):

There are two very decent virtual recreations around now - the TAL Bassline-101 and Roland's own Plug-Out 101. Could explain the resurgence.

The price of vintage analog synths in general has shot up a lot in the last few years.